# gsub pattern value to represent the hat sign

Tags: regex, r

Quick question for those that know the answer....what is the regex pattern that represents the "^" (the hat sign)? so that I can remove it when doing the following?

```
gsub("^","","^GSPC")
```

i.e. the output of the above is not `GSPC` as would be expected...

Comment: @mnel already covered everything, but here's a quote from `regex` help page. Hopefully you'll give it a read some day, it will be worth it. Anyway, the quote: `Any metacharacter with special meaning may be quoted by preceding it with a backslash.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to escape `^` because it is a regex metacharacter (as @Roman notes in comment)

```
gsub("\\^","","^GSPC")
```

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you just want to match a literal string of characters, you can set `fixed = TRUE` and then just type the string "verbatim". It makes for a more readable `pattern` argument, and is faster to boot!

```
gsub("^", "", "^GSPC", fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "GSPC"
```